# Trying to connect to mariadb running in docker

Tags: docker, socat

I have a database running in a docker container. It does not publish mariadb's port 3306.

Now I want to remotely log in to the docker host, connect to the container and access the database from my laptop

```
laptop ---> dockerhost ---> container
```

in order to access the database with gUI tools like DbVisualizer.

The idea is to open a connection with socat, but I'm stuck. Basically something like:

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:3306 EXEC:'ssh dockerhost sudo docker exec container "socat - TCP:localhost:3306"'
```

The last attempt failed with "Unexpected exception encountered during query." in DbVisualizer and "2019/09/10 12:19:54 socat[17462] E write(6, 0x7f9985803c00, 114): Broken pipe" in the shell.

The command was (broken for readability):

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:3306,forever,reuseaddr,fork \
exec:'
    ssh dockerhost \
        sudo docker exec container "
            socat STDIO TCP:localhost:3306,forever,reuseaddr,fork
        "
'
```

I hope someone can pinpoint what I do wrong or tell me how I can achieve my goal.

Comment: docker inspect containername ane copy its ip and give that ip in the connection, I don't know what's the problem but you can try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete and restart your container with a `docker run -p` or Docker Compose `ports:` option that will make it visible outside of Docker space.  (You're storing the actual database data in a volume, right?  On restart it will keep using the data from the volume.)

If you're comfortable with the container being accessed directly from off-host, then you can use an ordinary port invocation `-p 3306:3306` and then reach it using `dockerhost` as the host name and the first port number as the port number.

If you still want to require the ssh tunnel, you can cause the port to be bound to the Docker host's localhost interface, and then use ssh port forwarding.

```
dockerhost$ docker run -p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306 -v ... mysql
laptop$ ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 dockerhost
laptop$ mysql -h 127.0.0.1
```

`docker exec` in many ways is equivalent to `ssh root@...` and is not the normal way to interact with a network-accessible service.